# Creating turn() method to change horizontal direction

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm working on a class that includes a turn() method that's supposed to change the direction horizontally. The bug is moving left or right on a horizontal line.

Here's my code, I know it's wrong but I can't figure out how to change horizontal direction

```
class Bug:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.__name = ''
        self.__position = 0
        self.__direction = 180

    **def turn(self):
        if(self.__direction == 180):
            self.__direction = self.__direction - 180
        else:
            self.__direction = self.__direction + 180**

    def move(self):
        self.__position = self.__position + 1


    def getPosition(self):
        return self.__position
```

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction? I know it's super simple but I hit a block and can't figure it out!

Edit: I apologize for not being more clear! The move() method is just supposed to move the bug one unit in it's current direction. I also made an edit and removed self.__direction, as there are only supposed to be 2 instance variables, not 3. So basically all I need to fix is the turn() method, making my bug change direction (left or right on the horizontal line).

Comment: and what's wrong with your code?

Comment: You start with direction 180. After the first time calling `turn`, it is 0. After the second time calling it, it is 180 again. And so on. I cannot see anything wrong in this code.

Comment: Maybe you should actually use your direction in the `move` method in order to move the bug in the desired direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what you are trying to achieve, and I suppose that in the `move` method the actual direction should be taken into consideration:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

class Bug:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.__name = ''
        self.__position = position
        self.__direction = 1

    def turn(self):
        self.__direction = -self.__direction

    def move(self):
        self.__position = self.__position + self.__direction

    def getPosition(self):
        return self.__position

b = Bug (100)
for _ in range(5):
    b.move()
    print(b.getPosition())
b.turn()
for _ in range(5):
    b.move()
    print(b.getPosition())
```

This outputs:

```
101
102
103
104
105
104
103
102
101
100
```